# Replace and split line

Tags: python, replace, split

I tell you my problem.
One table like this:

```
    gi|494115682|ref|WP_007055464.1| MULTISPECIES: dephospho-CoA kinase [Bifidobacterium]
    gi|614110824|sp|P9WIB2.1|PHLB_MYCTO RecName: Full=Phospholipase C 2; Flags: Precursor
    gi|446269943|ref|WP_000347798.1| MULTISPECIES: amino acid ABC transporter permease [Vibrio]
    gi|446561267|ref|WP_000638613.1| acetyltransferase [Staphylococcus aureus]
```

When I make line.split('| ') to separate the last pipe '|', some line do not have the empty space just after and in the end I cant obtain a clear table.
For example:

> gi|614110824|sp|P9WIB2.1|PHLB_MYCTO RecName: Full=Phospholipase C 2; Flags: Precursor

My intention is to replace the last '|' to '\t' and after split by '\t'. using the line above, I can't split all lines at the position that I want.

```
for g in file:
    name = g.replace('| ', '|\t').
```

strip().split('\t')

If I first split by '|'
How can I correct this line to replace the fourth pipe, when surrounded, to a '| ' and after perform the split?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: can you post the result you want?

Comment: Why do You split on `'| '` instead of `'|'`? Use `|` without space and use -1th element of the list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
text = 'gi|494115682|ref|WP_007055464.1| MULTISPECIES: dephospho-CoA kinase [Bifidobacterium]'
text.rsplit('|',1)
```

out:

```
['gi|494115682|ref|WP_007055464.1',
 ' MULTISPECIES: dephospho-CoA kinase [Bifidobacterium]']
```

> str.rsplit(sep=None, maxsplit=-1)
>
> Return a list of the words in the
>   string, using sep as the delimiter string. If maxsplit is given, at
>   most maxsplit splits are done, the rightmost ones. If sep is not
>   specified or None, any whitespace string is a separator.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you actually want the csv module:

```
import io
import csv

file = io.StringIO('''
gi|494115682|ref|WP_007055464.1| MULTISPECIES: dephospho-CoA kinase [Bifidobacterium]
gi|614110824|sp|P9WIB2.1|PHLB_MYCTO RecName: Full=Phospholipase C 2; Flags: Precursor
gi|446269943|ref|WP_000347798.1| MULTISPECIES: amino acid ABC transporter permease [Vibrio]
gi|446561267|ref|WP_000638613.1| acetyltransferase [Staphylococcus aureus]
'''.strip())

reader = csv.reader(file, delimiter='|')
for row in reader:
    print(row)   # or print('\t'.join(row))
```